# How to give non changing unique keys to list items in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, key

I am trying to make an Input Component which Highlights the newly changed character. To make it happen I made the input element transparent and created a div absolutely position under it with same font size. Inside that div I render a list of span's with each character of the input string. to span I have applied an animation for 3s to change its color from red (highlighted) to black (normal).

Now to make list behave correctly I need to pass a key to each list item to uniquely identify each list item so that only the latest entered character gets highlighted and rest remains the same.

**What I have tried**

1. Use Index as keys.
   *works fine as long as I insert text in the end, but when any text is inserted in between the index of all following elements gets changed and therefore they all gets updated and therefore highlighted*
2. Use character as key. 
   *as we have only 26 characters as soon as any character repeats a have same keys for two different list items and again it behave strange*
3. Use character and context around as key (i.e, `ch + arr[index+1] + arr[index-1] etc..`)  
   *but again when it comes to similar patterns such as "aaaaa" etc.. it behaves unexpected.*
4. Use random numbers / id generators (uuid etc.) / new Date().getTime(). 
   *but as soon as elements updates render function gets called and all list items recieve brand new keys so they all update*
5. Use a counter in the parent component to count the total number of changes in the input field and assign that number as key to the newly added character component. 
   *I don't know how to Implement that because for that I need to check something like if the element doesn't already have a key assign the new number else keep the the old one.*

Is there any way to give new key (unique) to each list item based upon when it was created so that I can highlight only the changed element?

```
class Input extends Component {
  render() {
    let elems = null;
    let str = Array.from(this.props.value);
    elems = str.map((ch, i, arr) => (
      <span key={ch + arr[i - 1]} className="ch"> // .ch has animation to change color from red to black
        {ch}
      </span>
    ));
    return (
      <div className="fancyText">
        <input
          type={this.props.type}
          value={this.props.value}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          onChange={this.props.onChange} 
        /> // this one is transparent
        <div className="highlighted"> // this is visible
            {elems}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here is the [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-brook-vbq1o)*

Comment: Is it possible to get a minimal example up in a codesandbox? It'd be easier for other to tinker with the implementation.

Comment: I think in order to accomplish what you want, for the edgecases, you may need a separate structure to hold what index was just updated (either character changed or a new character inserted), and apply the animation to *just* that element.

Comment: @DrewReese Now I have given Sandbox link above

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you need, you can use a simply [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) called `uuid`.
In the class component first import it.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

Then you have to assign unique id for the very first parent tag of the component which will you're gonna reuse.

```
<span key={uuidv4()} className="ch">
    {ch}
  </span>
```

If you have a custom key then you can use it with uuid like this,

```
 <span key={uuidv4(YOUR_CUSTOM_KEY)} className="ch">
    {ch}
  </span>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Probably don't want to generate a unique ID every render cycle though.